# Saving results from genderize back into original csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv with a list of names that I want to put through the genderize package in python. I have done this successfully but now want to save the results back into the original csv. I know gender-api.com does this but I don't want to use that (money and supposed to be using python).

This is my code:

```
from genderize import Genderize
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Names.csv')
names = df['First Name']

print(Genderize().get(names))

Results: 
[{'name': 'Theresa', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 1.0, 'count': 834}, {'name': 'Andy', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.95, 'count': 3139}, {'name': 'Boris', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 1.0, 'count': 288}, {'name': 'Rachel', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 1.0, 'count': 4021}]
```

I would like my csv file to then have the additional columns: gender, probability and count, like it shows in the results.
New to coding so sorry if this is basic stuff. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert this result to dataframe then write it in csv:

```
result = [{'name': 'Theresa', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 1.0, 'count': 834}, {'name': 'Andy', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 0.95, 'count': 3139}, {'name': 'Boris', 'gender': 'male', 'probability': 1.0, 'count': 288}, {'name': 'Rachel', 'gender': 'female', 'probability': 1.0, 'count': 4021}]
resultDF = pd.DataFrame(result)
resultDF.to_csv('NewFile.csv')
```

Or, you can directly write the result into a csv:

```
import csv
keys = result[0].keys()
with open('newFile2.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(result)
```